# ember rails inserting data with empty fields

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-rails

Here is my form in template

```
<form>
  {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="comments" placeholder="Please type your comment here"}}
  <div class="form-footer">
   <button type="submit" class="btn pull-right btn-primary" tabindex="100" {{action saveIndianize}}>Save</button> 
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is my js model

```
App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
    post_id: DS.attr('number'),
    user_id: DS.attr('number'),
    comments: DS.attr('string'),
    created_at: DS.attr('date'),
    job: DS.belongsTo('App.Post',{embedded:true}),
});
```

This is my serializer

```
attributes :id,:post_id,:user_id,:comments,:created_at
```

Here is my rails controller

```
@comment = Comment.new(user_id: params[:user_id],post_id: params[:post_id],comments: params[:comments])
```

When i submit the form throwing error as

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key comments but you have no mapping for it
```

It is inserting into database with id(primary key), created_at and updated_at. But i couldn't see `user_id, post_id` and `comments`.

How can i solve it.

Comment: What is the version of ember.js and ember-data?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have two problems here.

First, I think that `user_id`, `post_id` and `comments` are probably not being set due to mass assignment protection.  If you're using Rails 4 you'll want to look into Strong Parameters and if you're on Rails 3 you'll want to investigate `attr_accessible`.

The error has to do with the JSON format that you are returning.  You'll want to make sure that the JSON returns a main key of `comment` (singular), and not `comments` (plural).

```
{ "comment" : {...} }
```

Not :

```
{ "comments" : {...} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes in my controller solved

`@comment = Comment.new(user_id: params[:comments][:user_id],post_id: params[:comments][:post_id],comments: params[:comments][:comments])`